# My scanner keeps getting the error "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, int, java.util.scanner

I am having a problem because when I try to compile my code it says that that scanner can't be found as a symbol.

What can I do to fix it ?

```
public class Unit10
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    scanner input =  new scanner(System.in);
        int numEmployees;
        System.out.println( "How many employees do you wish to enter?" );
        numEmployees = input.nextInt();
        Employee[] employeeArray = new Employee[numEmployees]; 
        for ( int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++ ) 
        {
            Employee e1 = new Employee();  
            Name first = new Name();
            Name last = new Name();
            System.out.println( "Enter the first name of the employee" );
            e1.setFirstName( input.nextLine() );
            System.out.println( "Enter the last name of the employee" );
            e1.setLastName( input.nextLine() );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner` is a class, and every class in the library starts with an upper-case letter:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: When I change that cases of both Scanners it is still saying "cannot find symbol"

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported java.util.scanner at the start of your program?

Also, I think it's "Scanner" and not "scanner"

Answer (score 0):

Use this import:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: Now that I have added import java.util.Scanner; it is saying that import is an illegal start to the expression and util.Scanner is not a statement

Comment: The import statement has to go before the class definition.

Comment: As npostavs has said, it needs to be before the class definition. In other words at the top of the file, above all other code.